# (third) Clean Ubuntu 20.04 install seems to be somehow crippled

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-studio

HP EliteBook 8470p, 8GB, new SSD 256GB,  Intel Core i5-3320M (2.60 GHz, 3MB L3 cache, 35 W, 2 cores)

Just 4 days ago I had Ubuntu 18.04 that was very stable for almost 3 uears.
Now i installed Ubuntu for 3 times: Ubuntu, Ubuntu, Ubuntu Studio and every time something is wrong while working on it. I'm very sorry, that here and there i will write just about "wrong/strange behaviour" as there are really many things and i can't remember all.

Installation from USB, different mirrors images. First usb made on Win, second made on Ubuntu with Disks.

1. First installation Ubuntu (minimal apps, additional repos enabled) didn't even manage to boot. Computer was just time after time subsequently restarting.
2. Second Ubuntu (minimal apps). Restart after installation hanged with blinking cursor. After hard restart it stand up and worked but... next shutdown also not managed it. After that problem disappeared.

Apps frequently caused msgs dialog "Ubuntu crashed" and those were various apps. Particular app: Gnome Tweaks after some minute or so, started to loose some window functionality eg. window buttons and had many strange behaviours. Just uninstalled it. After some time installed once again it behaved wrong again.

On 16.04, 18.04 I used to very good Ubuntu installer. On 20.04 notoriously can't install app because of some dependency problems i suspect (cos apts etc. had those kind of problems with those apps). Or it installed app and it was not visible in menu etc.
Most funny was disappearing of Chrome. When reinstalled, it was still logged to Gmail etc.
As fun story on margin: tried to install Ubuntu Studio controlls and it started to complain on many dependecies eg. such that IT should install after it IS already installed.

Almost 75% of audio plugins didn't manage to install or failed to work. Eg. Vital, Surge, ZynAddSubFx, Geonkick.

3. Ubuntu Studio (full std. apps, no additional repos) - installed OK.
   Same behaviour of apps - msgs "Ubuntu crashed". First was just Settings Manager and then some others.

This was today mornig, after this i checked new SSD with Disks "Smart data& Self-tests" and it shows OK.

So now i'm on clean "somehow crippled" Ubuntu Studio writing this post.
In general I have feeling to use some home-made alpha version OS. Don't know what to do because i used to Ubuntu and don't want to look for other distro. Also not fun for me installing short live 20.10.

Comment: Can your hardware handle 20.04? Fresh installs or some kind of upgrade? https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-system-requirements#:~:text=Virtualized%20Ubuntu%20Desktop%20Edition,-If%20you're&text=2%20GHz%20single%20core%20processor,GB%20of%20hard%20drive%20space

Comment: Fresh installs. Hardware is not new but for me more than enought.

Comment: Is it enough for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Yes it is. Additionally checked CPU Intel Core i5-3320M (2.60 GHz, 3MB L3 cache, 35 W, 2 cores). The rest is more that enougth. I'm goin also to reinstall to 18.04 to check for sure if it will work properly. Don't belive in sudden hardware failure though.

Comment: While older, you may have newer UEFI from HP. If so update it. Also SSD often need firmware updates. Was old install Legacy or UEFI? That should be an UEFI system, but some HPs just have issues.

Comment: Ok, this was legacy install like 16 and 18 before. Going UEFI. Be right back with update.

Comment: Installed 18.04 from DVD and then did upgrade to 20.04. Works. Tried to create answer with this resolution, but some very wise man deleted it. Bye.